# Elementary Geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles

The side of the square measures $1\  \mathrm{cm}$ , and $AC = 1\  \mathrm{cm}$, find the value of $AB$

[image: picture]

Comment: At first glance I'd suggest using similar triangles and Pythagoras and then bashing it out with algebra but that would be no fun (nor am I sure whether it'd work). Hoping someone posts some simplistically marvelous proof

Answer (score 2):

**First try:**

There are 3 rectangular triangles here, where we get 3 Pythagoras from:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1^2+(1-d)^2&=&c^2\\
a^2+d^2&=&1^2\\
(1+a)^2+1^2&=&(1+c)^2,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
with $a=\overline{AB}$,$d=\overline{BC}$ and $c=\overline{0C}$, where $0$ is the upper left point. With this, we ask [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/83p9zs7) to get 
$$
d=\overline{AB}\approx 0.883204 = \frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt{2}-1+\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1} \right)
$$

---

**Second try:**

We have $\sin \alpha= \frac{a}{1}= \frac{1+a}{1+c}$ and $1+(1-d)^2=c^2$. 
Further, since $d=\cos( \arcsin (a) )=\sqrt{1-a^2}$, we get
$$
a=\frac{1+a}{1+\sqrt{1+(1-d)^2}}=\frac{1+a}{1+\sqrt{1+(1-\sqrt{1-a^2})^2}}, \tag{*}
$$
with the same solution as [above](http://tinyurl.com/72wv29f).
$(*)$ can be reformulated to 
$$
a^8-2a^6+7a^4-6a^2+1=A^4-2A^3+7A^2-6A+1=0,
$$
where the roots of polynomial of $4$th order can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function). But because it works out nice, let's go one step further and substitute $a=u+1/2$, so we get:
$$
u^4+\frac{11}{2}u^2-\frac{7}{16}=0.
$$
From here on, the rest is left to you. Nice Question!

Comment: Reminds me on one of own [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/106824/19341) about various proofs...

Answer (score 2):

Let D and E be the endpoints of the upper side of the square. We know that   $\triangle DEC \cong \triangle ABC. $ Therefore, we have the following: $$EC= \frac{1}{AB+1} ; 1=(1-EC)^2 + AB^2 $$ Solving for $AB$, we have $$ AB^4 + 2AB^3+AB^2-2AB-1 =0$$ Since we know that $0 \le AB \le 1,$ we apply the newton's method by letting $1$ be our initial value in the first iteration. Then we have: $$AB= 0.8832035059$$

Comment: The triangles should be similar which implies I make use of its idea that corresponding ratios are equal to simplify the messy algebraic manipulation

Answer (score 1):

OK, maybe not a perfect solution, but I managed to transform it into a degree-4 equation.

Let's call the top-left vertex D. Let's call DC x and AB y. Using pythagoras theorem, one can see easily that $(1 + x)^2 = (1 + y)^2 + 1^2$. If we look at the angles CAB and CDE (where E is the top right vertex). They are the same. We can compute their cosine from both angles, once as $1/x$ and the other as $(1+y)/(1+x)$.

If we do the substitution and simplify we get $x^4 + 2x^3 - x^2 -2x - 1 = 0$. Remembering we are trying to compute y.We substitute $y = 1/x$ and get the same answer as draks'.

Comment: Whoops.. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I get $(\pm\sqrt{5+4\sqrt{2}}-1)/2=1.13224$ (resp. $-2.13224$) as root of your polynomial, which corresponds to $\overline{DC}$.

Comment: @draks yes, we are trying to get y, which is 1/x = 0.8832035059

Comment: @draks but I'll make that clearer in the answer. Thanks!